# how to show/hide comments in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

How can i hide/show comments on visual studio 2019 i tried the extention 'HideShow Comments' but i did not work work with the version 2019 of vs
somethink like this :
comments activated :

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Syncroniously reads specified number of ushorts starting from specified address in data memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startAddress">Address to start to read from</param>
    /// <param name="count">Number of ushorts to read</param>
    /// <returns>Read data</returns>
    public ushort[] ReadData(ushort startAddress, ushort count)
    {
        var sid = IncrementSid();
        var cmd = FinsDriver.ReadDataCommand(new Header(sid, true), startAddress, count);
        return Read(sid, cmd);
    }
```

and comments disabled :

```
  public ushort[] ReadData(ushort startAddress, ushort count)
    {
        var sid = IncrementSid();
        var cmd = FinsDriver.ReadDataCommand(new Header(sid, true), startAddress, count);
        return Read(sid, cmd);
    }
```

Comment: To hide the selected code or area (first, select the area), just use Ctrl + M, Ctrl + H. This works for any selection. and you can use this link  <a href="https://www.helixoft.com/blog/collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c.html?n=collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c">https://www.helixoft.com/blog/collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c.html?n=collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c</a>

Comment: thanks but is there is any other solution ?

Comment: you can use NoCommnet [link]( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment)

Answer (score 3):

There are some VS extensions that might do what you want.

- [NoComment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment) - hides comments and replaces them with a callout icon. Comments are shown as tooltip and when editing them.
- [CommentsRemover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kipattab.CommentsRemover) - removes both single line and multi-line comments from current active document/project/solution while preserving documentation headers (File header, Class headers & method headers) and those.
- [Collapse Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.CollapseComments) - adds a command to collapse comments in the open code file.

Comment: Got so excited when I saw NoComent. I've thought of this exact tool and hoped for it for years... but won't install on Visual Studio 2022 :( :( :(